# SCNText Not Displaying

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have the following code in my SceneKit application but for some reason the text never shows up on the screen.

```
 let text = SCNText(string: item.label, extrusionDepth: 4.0)
            text.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
            text.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 35)

            let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
            textNode.position = SCNVector3(-0.2 + x, -0.9 + delta, -1)

            self.node.addChildNode(textNode)
```

Comment: We need some more code here. What is `self`, how is your scene set up, where is the camera?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using .font, try using .scale. Even a 1 for font is still a meter tall, so scaling it down might be needed. This worked for me: textNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01,0.01,0.01)

Answer (score 2):

With a size of 35, that text will be huge. It's not 35 points tall, but 35 SceneKit units tall. It's quite possible that the text is visible, but your camera is peering through a hole in a letter, or the Z limit on your camera is stopping it from rendering.

Comment: This was the issue that helped me. Without specifying the font size, I had to scale the text down 100 times to see it at a reasonable size on screen

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bug in how ARKit is transforming SCNText nodes. See these for reference:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/235611#235611
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79715